# Not able to select correct Image due to incorrect position value of getView in Adapter extending ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter, getview

I am trying to create a gridView of scrollable images for my android app.Each Grid consist of imageView. When one clicks on the image, then it blurs the image and present Play & share options.I am using the ArrayAdapter with holder pattern to set the view.

**Problem Statement:-**

I am handling click event on BlurLayout in the Adapter. On click i play the video related to image in youtube player. The problem is that in getView of ArrayAdapter, value of position is coming incorrectly. Thus it plays a wrong video. My observation is that position value is correct for 0-2 and it repeats.

Code Snippet:-

```
    public class TrendingAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<TrendingData>  {

        private AdapterCallback mAdapterCallback;
        final private DbHandler db;

        public TrendingAdapter(Context context, int resource, AdapterCallback callback) {
            super(context, resource);

            this.mAdapterCallback = callback;
            this.db  = new DbHandler(getContext());

        }

        //hover image
        private BlurLayout mSampleLayout ;



        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
            final ViewHolder holder;

            if( convertView == null ) {

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from( getContext() ).inflate( R.layout.activity_trending_adapter, parent, false );
                holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById( R.id.image );
                holder.caption=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);

                convertView.setTag(holder);

                BlurLayout.setGlobalDefaultDuration(450);
                mSampleLayout = (BlurLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.blur_layout);
                final View hover = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.hover_sample, null);

                holder.play = (ImageView)hover.findViewById(R.id.heart);
                holder.playList = (ImageView)hover.findViewById(R.id.share);


                hover.findViewById(R.id.play).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        YoYo.with(Techniques.Tada)
                                        .duration(550)
                                        .playOn(v);


                        mAdapterCallback.onMethodCallback(getItem(position).getImage(), getItem(position).getCaption(),getItem(position).getBgImage());

                    }
                        });

                hover.findViewById(R.id.playlist).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        YoYo.with(Techniques.Swing)
                                .duration(550)
                                .playOn(v);
                        String date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy").format(new Date());



db.addContact(new PlayListData(getItem(position).getThumbnail(), getItem(position).getCaption(),date,getItem(position).getImage()));



                    }
                });

                mSampleLayout.setHoverView(hover);
                mSampleLayout.setBlurDuration(550);
                mSampleLayout.addChildAppearAnimator(hover, R.id.heart, Techniques.FlipInX, 550, 0);
                mSampleLayout.addChildAppearAnimator(hover, R.id.share, Techniques.FlipInX, 550, 250);
                mSampleLayout.addChildAppearAnimator(hover, R.id.more, Techniques.FlipInX, 550, 500);

                mSampleLayout.addChildDisappearAnimator(hover, R.id.heart, Techniques.FlipOutX, 550, 500);
                mSampleLayout.addChildDisappearAnimator(hover, R.id.share, Techniques.FlipOutX, 550, 250);
                mSampleLayout.addChildDisappearAnimator(hover, R.id.more, Techniques.FlipOutX, 550, 0);

                mSampleLayout.addChildAppearAnimator(hover, R.id.description, Techniques.FadeInUp);
                mSampleLayout.addChildDisappearAnimator(hover, R.id.description, Techniques.FadeOutDown);



            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }


            final ViewHolder tmp = holder;


            Picasso.with(getContext()).load(getItem(position).getThumbnail())
                    .placeholder(getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.place)).
                    error(getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.place)).
                    into(holder.image);



            return convertView;
        }



        private class ViewHolder {
            ImageView   image;
            TextView    caption;
            ImageView   play;
            ImageView   playList;

        }
    }
```

The Value of position is incorrect in:-

```
   mAdapterCallback.onMethodCallback(getItem(position).getImage(), getItem(position).getCaption(),getItem(position).getBgImage());

    db.addContact(new PlayListData(getItem(position).getThumbnail(), getItem(position).getCaption(),date,getItem(position).getImage()));
```

I don't how to get the correct value of position so that i can play the correct video against image (Play button in BlurLayout) on which the click event happens.

Please help to resolve the problem.

**Edit 1:-
Adding TrendingData Class**

```
 public class TrendingData {

        private String thumbnail;
        private String image;
        private String caption;
        private String bg_image;

        public TrendingData() {

        }

        public TrendingData( String thumbnail, String image, String caption, String bg_image ) {
            //this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
            this.thumbnail = bg_image;
            this.image = image;
            this.caption = caption;
            this.bg_image = bg_image;
        }

        public String getThumbnail() {
            return thumbnail;
        }

        public void setThumbnail(String thumbnail) {
            this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
        }

        public String getImage() {
            return image;
        }

        public String getBgImage() {
            return bg_image;
        }

        public void setImage(String image) {
            this.image = image;
        }

        public void setBgImage(String bg_image) {
            this.bg_image = bg_image;
        }

        public String getCaption() {
            return caption;
        }

        public void setCaption(String caption) {
            this.caption = caption;
        }
    }
```

Please help i am stuck for days now and I have tried everything i can find.

Comment: kindly show TrendingData class

Comment: Pankaj any idea, what could be the problem?

Comment: well if your data is mismatched with each other in object, Kindly check the instance variable's value for each TrendingData object before you past the it's ArrayList to the your custom adapter and remove  **<TrendingData >** from your adapter, get the arraylist instead in the constructor

Comment: I think the value of position is incorrect, because of holder pattern, getView is called in reusable manner and controlled by android.  So, even when i scroll to the any image, getView has different position value, most of the time it's 0. I think some how i need to get position value from the current view that has the focus or touched. I don't how to do that. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't see your are setting any values for the instance variable of **TrendingData**, i guess the images that you can see, is simple read from the layout where you have defined it